# Add Values between 2 NSMutableDictionary

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutabledictionary

I need add values from 2 NSMutableDictionary here is my example but not working =(

```
NSMutableDictionary *coord  = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
NSMutableDictionary *data = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

data = [dao obtenerDatosFinales];
```

**And y need get two values objectForKey and fill the other NSMutableDictionary (coord)**

```
coord =    [data objectForKey:@"latitud"];
coord =    [data objectForKey:@"longitud"];

NSLog(@"Dictionary: %@", [coord description])!
```

**but only fill one key. Have any idea? Tanks!**

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to output what is shown? Or are you trying to replicate the data? I'm unclear as to what you want the final goal to be.

Comment: That makes no sense.  You set the same value "coord" from two different operations (apparently one right after the other, so the first result is thrown away), and then apparently do nothing with "coord".  If this is what you're really doing you need to drop Objective-C for awhile and learn Java or something to get a basic understanding of sequential programming.

Comment: (By the way, your "Dictionary" above is an NSArray.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code:

1. Creates an empty dictionary in "coord".
2. Then it extracts an element from "data" and sets "coord" to that
   object, thus replacing the original dictionary that you created in
   the first step.
3. Then it extracts a different object, and sets "coord" to that new
   object, thus replacing the object from the second step.

You're going to have to describe what you want to do more clearly.

You might do something like this:

```
NSString *key;
id anObject;

key = @"latitud";
anObject = [data objectForKey: key];
[coord setObject: anObject forKey: key];


key = @"longitud";
anObject = [data objectForKey: key];
[coord setObject: anObject forKey: key];
```